# A die is thrown $k$ times. How to determine the sum equal to $k$?

Tags: probability, statistics, summation, dice

A die is thrown $k$ times. Compute the probability of these resulting sums:

- $k$
- $k+1$

In this problem I assume that the die is $6$-sided and that the answer should be in terms of $k$.

[Formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3614/how-to-easily-determine-the-results-distribution-for-multiple-dice):  $p(x)^n = x^n (1 - x^6) (1-x)^n$

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Let's look at just two dice. There are 36 possible outcomes on two dice, but you can achieve any sum from 2 to 12 (11 possible values). But, not every value is equiprobable. To get a sum of 2, you need to roll a 1 twice (one way in 36). To get a sum of 3, you need a 1 and a 2 or a 2 and a 1 (two ways in 36). Etc. It will be useful to think of it this way when solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use probability generating functions, then a single die corresponds to $\frac16(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)$  and so for $k$ dice: $$\left(\frac{x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6}{6}\right)^k=\left(\frac{x(1-x^6)}{6(1-x)}\right)^k$$

If you expand this you get $$\tfrac{1}{6^k}x^k +\tfrac{k}{6^k}x^{k+1}+\tfrac{k(k+1)}{2\times 6^k}x^{k+2}+\cdots + \tfrac{k(k+1)}{2\times 6^k}x^{6k-2}+\tfrac{k}{6^k}x^{6k-1}+\tfrac{1}{6^k}x^{6k}$$

so from the coefficients of the first two terms

- the probability of getting $k$ is $\frac{1}{6^k}$
- the probability of getting $k+1$ is $\frac{k}{6^k}$

Comment: Thank you @Henry ! Exactly the binomial expansion I was looking for. Now I can solve not only for $k + 1$, but also $k + n$ for $n ≤ 6$

Answer (score 9):

The only way to get $k$ as an answer is if all rolls are $1$, so the probability is $\frac{1}{6^k}$.

To get $k+1$ all rolls must be $1$ except for one roll which is a $2$; there are therefore $k$ different ways to do this and the probability is $\frac{k}{6^k}$.

Comment: I was just about to post that answer, almost verbatim (+1).

Comment: Could you elaborate on $k + 1$'s formula? The first one actually makes total sense, but it would be helpful to get a formula and simplify that step by step to get $\frac{k}{6^k}$, due to having to show the 'working out'.

Comment: @AvaBarbilla The reasoning given in the answer is the “working out.”